# subclassing nssegmentedcontrol?

Tags: objective-c, button, subclass, segment, nssegmentedcontrol

What's the best way to create controls like this?

[image]

I'm assuming it's an NSSegmentedControl and I have to subclass the cell?  But wanted to get a second opinion.  Thanks,

rc

Note: the lighter control is from Twitter Mac and the darker are from Rapidweaver.

Answer (score -1):

[ANSegmentedControl](https://github.com/Decors/ANSegmentedControl)

OR

Take one UIImageView, and

- set default look image
- put transparent buttons on each segment
- on button action, change the UIImageView image to selected button and perform action.

Comment: are you talking about mac osx app ?

Comment: you just have to put the buttons on image view and change the image of that uiimage view.

Comment: would you show me an example of this way ?, Because I think the behavior between UIKit And AppKit is a lot different

Comment: this looks promising one .. please edit your answer and copy the link into it. thanks

Answer (score -2):

[image]

1. First take one UIImageView and get the three images for each tab selected.
2. on UIImageView place three UILabels for title
3. On each segment put UIButton button with custom style
4. When you click on any button

   1. change UIImageView image to selected segment
   2. Change the UILabel color to whatever you want to highlight
   3. Perform action you want to do

Comment: I can not find UIImageView on AppKit Object Library.

Comment: you want it for os x app then it will be NSImageView

Comment: I gave you way to do it in iOS, now you just have to implement with osx classes.

Comment: okay. Actually I can't find how I should do this with drag'n'drop IB. Is it perhaps I have to to do it by the code to draw custom nsimageview ?